# How can I set override default kwargs in a parent class?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following parent and child classes:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = kwargs.get('a', 'default_A')
        self.b = kwargs.get('b', 'default_B')

class B(A):

    a = "override_A"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)

b = B()

print b.b  # this is "default_B", as expected
print b.a  # I expected this to be "override_A"
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried to understand how inheritance works via answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19205946) but haven't found something that describes this specific requirement.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just added the semantic print statements. If you run the exact code you'll quickly realize that the issue is not a printing error.

Comment: Yep, I've edited the question to hopefully make that clearer. You hadn't distinguished which outputs were expected and which weren't.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16852860/3001761

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're mixing class and instance variables. `B.a` is a class variable, which is shadowed by the instance variable set in `A.__init__()`.

You could for example use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
class B(A):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If the key 'a' exists, this'll be effectively no-operation.
        # If not, then 'a' is set to 'override_A'.
        kwargs.setdefault('a', 'override_A')
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Why the `(ab)` though? This is a perfectly fine use of `setdefault()`.